# Passing Vectors as Arguments in functions R

Tags: r

I would like to pass vectors as arguments in functions on R.

I want the function to have two Input vectors and output vector name.

Something like

```
ExampleFunction < - function(c(1,2),c(3,4),unionvector)
{
A<- firstvector
B<- SecondVector
unionvector <- A union B Vector
}
```

The result I want it to be like :-  1 2 inside the A vector 3 4 inside the B Vector & 1 2 3 4  inside the unionvector

I am not able to pass the Input vectors inside the arguments and can't get the ExampleFunction working.

Comment: OK. And what is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass vector as arguments when making a call to the function. Use this:

```
exampleFunction<-function(A,B){
    return(unionvector=c(A,B))
}

exampleFunction(c(1,2),c(3,4))
#[1] 1 2 3 4
```

**or**

```
exampleFunction<-function(A=c(1,2),B=c(3,4)){
     return(unionvector=c(A,B))
 } 
exampleFunction()
#[1] 1 2 3 4
```